# Vue2 + jQuery + jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, vuejs2

How can I use jQuery and jQuery-UI i a single Vue.js component ? What would be the best way of importing these two and making them work together ?

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

I tried the import above, and it works, but then how do I add the jquery-ui ?

Answer:
Final code of Vue component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <input id="test" />
</template>
<script>
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker'
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css'
export default {
  name: 'Dashboard',
  mounted(){
    $("#test").datepicker()
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a few years late to the party but I had the same problem with Vue3. I can easily add Jquery to the Vue app itself within main.js, but I can't seem to add Jquery-UI functionality

```
//Main.js
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui'; 
//This doesn't throw any errors in Vue CLI, but all jquery-UI functions return 'not a function' error
```

In the end, I removed Jquery from main.js and instead added the Jquery & Jquery-UI scripts into public/index.html like so...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">

  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but Apprentice Buddy doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-lSjKY0/srUM9BE3dPm+c4fBo1dky2v27Gdjm2uoZaL0=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  </script>
</html>
```

You should still be able to use Jquery in Vue component methods. *If it's not already obvious, Jquery is being added globally, it is not localised to specific components.*

Answer (score 0):

Simply `import 'jquery-ui';` after your line should do the trick.
Better: import only those aspects of interest for you: E.g import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable';

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I can import jquery, but 'jquery-ui' doesn't update jquery with plugins